# Snowflake: how to allow only Key Pair Authentication connections?

Tags: authentication, snowflake

Is there any way to configure Snowflake to allow only key pair authenticated users' connections?

At the moment you [can add `RSA_PUBLIC_KEY_FP`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#private-key-file-name-and-password-as-connection-properties) to any user. But he can connect easily without specifying the key file.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution:

1. Create public/private key pair
2. Assign public key to a Snowflake user, e.g.
   `alter user testuser set rsa_public_key='ADNDDBgkqh...';`
3. Set the user's password to `null`: `alter user testuser set password = null;`
4. For connection don't forget to specify properties: `private_key_file` and `private_key_file_pwd`